# How to add imageviews to constraint layout

Tags: android, layout, imageview, android-constraintlayout

I have a Constraint Layout. I added imageviews to Constraint Layout programmatically that have random pictures. When user clicked "New Game" button, i want to remove all imageviews that created programmatically and recreate them randomly.

When i wrote the code below, my images are being created but old images are also remaining. How can i reload my constraint layout without old imageviews?

CLCarrier.addView(Cards[i], -1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few different ways you could do this.

### Remove all views from your ConstraintLayout

All `ViewGroup` subclasses support the `removeAllViews()` method. This will remove every child currently in the ViewGroup, so it's only appropriate if you want to get rid of *everything*. If there are some views you want to keep around, this won't work.

### Track the ImageViews as you add them, and then remove them one-by-one

Perhaps you keep a `List<ImageView> images` variable somewhere, and as you add images to your ConstraintLayout, you also call `images.add(myImageView)`. This will then give you a collection of views you can iterate over and call `removeView()` on:

```
for (ImageView image : images) {
    constraintLayout.removeView(image);
}
```

### Re-inflate the original ConstraintLayout

If you don't want to use `removeAllViews()` and you also don't want to track all the views so that you can remove them later, you could re-initialize your ConstraintLayout by re-inflating the original layout.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this); // requires a `Context` object
constraintLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.constraint_layout, parent, false);
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, your answer was so explanatory.